# Break of "switch" is breaking two levels

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs

I'm using RN 0.57.1 which is Babel 7. But this is just a "javascript" question.

I can't reproduce yet (even in same loop with another switch block) and have worked all day. I'm continuing to try to figure this out by investigating the transpiled code. But for some weird reason, the `break` statements in the `switch` are breaking the parent `while` loop. I had to replace them with `break PUSH_KIND_SWITCH`. If I use regular `break` it causes the problem. I was just posting here if anyone can see anything wrong while I continue to investigate:

Untranspiled code:

```
function* pushWorker(message: PushMessage, accountId: AccountId, calendarId: CalendarId): Generator<*, void, *> {

    // if no channel for this id, create a channel for it
    const accCalId = buildAccCalId(accountId, calendarId);
    // console.log('in pushWorker, message:', message);
    const { id } = message;

    let buf, chan;
    {
        const { id } = message;
        if (pushChanById.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            console.log('channel already in pushChanById, will put to it, id:', id);
            pushChanById[id].put(message);
            return;
        } else {
            console.log('creating channel');
            buf = buffers.expanding(1)
            pushChanById[id] = yield call(channel, buf);
            // pushChanById[id].put(message);
        }

        chan = pushChanById[id];
    }

    // console.log('material for id:', id, 'buf:', buf, 'chan:', chan);

    PUSH_MESSAGE_LOOP:
    while (true) {
        console.log('at top of while-loop for saga for event id:', id);
        console.log('got message in chan, message:', message, 'will check newerMessages (which are newer then this current message) to see if this newer should cancel & ovveride this message');

        console.log('will delay 5s to allow user to batch actions - for instance undo is allowed for 4sec, so that would cancel the create');
        yield call(delay, 5000);
        console.log('done delay');

        // remove all newer messages in channel, and boil it down to one message to act on
        const newerMessages = yield flush(chan);
        console.log('newerMessages in chan:', newerMessages, 'recall that current message is:', message);

        message = newerMessages.last || message;
        console.log('checked newerMessages, and decided message to act on is:', message);

        // act on message
        let { kind } = message;
        let event = yield select(selectEvent, id);

        if (!event) {
            console.warn('EVENT NO LONGER EXISTS, so disccarding, and skipping switch block and skip to kill the channel this SHOULD NEVER HAPPEN');
        } else {

            const meta = getPushMeta(event, accountId, calendarId);
            const isRemoteExisting = meta.sid !== undefined;
            if (kind === PK.create && isRemoteExisting) {
                console.log('kind was create, but isRemoteExisting, so change this to update!');
                kind = PK.update;
            } else if (kind === PK.update && !isRemoteExisting) {
                console.log('kind was update, but isRemoteExisting is false!!, so change this to create!');
                kind = PK.create;
            }

            PUSH_KIND_SWITCH:
            switch (kind) {
                case PK.delete: {
                        const calendar = (yield select(selectActiveCalendar)) || { id:'primary' };
                        const calendarId = calendar.id;
                        const remoteEventId = meta.sid; // if !isRemoteExisting then this will be undefined

                        let status;
                        if (isRemoteExisting) {
                            ({ status } = yield call(
                                fetch,
                                `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${calendarId}/events/${remoteEventId}`,
                                {
                                    method: 'delete'
                                }
                            ));
                        }

                        if (!isRemoteExisting || status === 204 || status === 410) {
                            // 410 - P error:{ code:410, errors:[...], message:'Resource has been delete' }

                            yield put(patchEvent(id, {
                                pushMetaByAccCalId: {
                                    [accCalId]: {
                                        accCalId,
                                        accountId,
                                        calendarId,
                                        sid: undefined,
                                        version: event.version
                                    }
                                }
                            }));

                            // TODO: think about also making sure there are no more messages, probably with a buf.isEmpty(), cuz what if another came in to undo it?
                            // check if deleted from all other accounts, if so then _deleteEvent
                            const otherMetas = Object.values(event.pushMetaByAccCalId || {}).filter(meta => meta.accCalId !== accCalId); // remove this account, as we know for sure it was pushed. no need to do a `yield select()`
                            const isLatestRemoteExistOnAllAccounts = otherMetas.every(otherMeta => [undefined, event.version].includes(otherMeta.version)); // undefined because latest remote is a deleted, so if others are undefined great it never got anything
                            event = yield select(selectEvent, id);
                            if (isLatestRemoteExistOnAllAccounts && !testIfRecording(event)) yield put(_deleteEvent(id));
                        } else {
                            console.warn('failed to delete, i should keep retrying this, until another message comes in to chan canceling this one?');
                        }
                    break;
                }
                case PK.create: {
                        const calendar = (yield select(selectActiveCalendar)) || { id:'primary' };
                        const calendarId = calendar.id;

                        const { title, summary } = extractTitleAndSummary(event.memo);

                        const { reply, status } = yield call(
                            fetch,
                            `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${calendarId}/events`,
                            {
                                method: 'post',
                                body: {
                                    summary: title,
                                    description: summary,
                                    start: {
                                        dateTime: moment(event.start).toISOString()
                                    },
                                    end: {
                                        dateTime: moment(event.end).toISOString()
                                    },
                                    location: event.location
                                }
                            }
                        );

                        if (status === 200) {
                            yield put(patchEvent(id, {
                                pushMetaByAccCalId: {
                                    [accCalId]: {
                                        accCalId,
                                        accountId,
                                        calendarId,
                                        sid: reply.id,
                                        version: event.version
                                    }
                                }
                            }));
                        } else {
                            console.warn('failed to insert event, i should keep retrying this, until another message comes in to chan canceling this one?');
                        }
                    break;
                }
                case PK.update: {
                        const calendarId = get(yield select(), ['prefs', 'calendar', 'id'], 'primary');
                        const remoteEventId = meta.sid;

                        const { title, summary } = extractTitleAndSummary(event.memo);

                        const { reply, status } = yield call(
                            fetch,
                            `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${calendarId}/events/${remoteEventId}`,
                            {
                                method: 'put',
                                body: {
                                    summary: title,
                                    description: summary,
                                    start: {
                                        dateTime: moment(event.start).toISOString()
                                    },
                                    end: {
                                        dateTime: moment(event.end).toISOString()
                                    },
                                    location: event.location
                                }
                            }
                        );

                        if (status === 200) {
                            yield put(patchEvent(id, {
                                pushMetaByAccCalId: {
                                    [accCalId]: {
                                        accCalId,
                                        accountId,
                                        calendarId,
                                        sid: reply.id,
                                        version: event.version
                                    }
                                }
                            }));
                        } else {
                            console.warn('failed to update event, i should keep retrying this, until another message comes in to chan canceling this one?');
                        }
                    break;
                }
            }
            // console.log('out of switch MUST SEE');
        }
        // console.log('out of if-else MUST SEE');

        // destroy channel if channel is empty, else continue the while loop to process next message
        if (buf.isEmpty()) {
            console.log('buf is empty for event id:', id, 'so destroying channel and quiting pushSaga for it');
            chan.close();
            delete pushChanById[id];

            yield put(patchEvent(id, { status:undefined })); // set status to undefined, as push is complete. if event is deleted, it just wont do anything
            break PUSH_MESSAGE_LOOP;
        } else {
            console.log('at bottom of while-loop, and there are more messages so immediately take next message, for saga for event id:', id);
            message = yield take(chan);
            console.log('got another message from chan while at bottom, message:', message);
        }
    }
    // console.log('out of while if did not see 2x "MUST SEE" this is a bug');
}
```

## TRANSPILED CODE

```
  function pushWorker(message, accountId, calendarId) {
    var accCalId, _message, id, buf, chan, _message2, _id, _loop, _ret;

    return _regenerator.default.wrap(function pushWorker$(_context14) {
      while (1) {
        switch (_context14.prev = _context14.next) {
          case 0:
            accCalId = (0, _utils2.buildAccCalId)(accountId, calendarId);
            _message = message, id = _message.id;
            _message2 = message, _id = _message2.id;

            if (!pushChanById.hasOwnProperty(_id)) {
              _context14.next = 9;
              break;
            }

            console.log('channel already in pushChanById, will put to it, id:', _id);

            pushChanById[_id].put(message);

            return _context14.abrupt("return");

          case 9:
            console.log('creating channel');
            buf = _reduxSaga.buffers.expanding(1);
            _context14.next = 13;
            return (0, _effects.call)(_reduxSaga.channel, buf);

          case 13:
            pushChanById[_id] = _context14.sent;

          case 14:
            chan = pushChanById[_id];
            _loop = _regenerator.default.mark(function _loop() {
              var newerMessages, _message3, kind, event, meta, isRemoteExisting, calendar, _calendarId, remoteEventId, status, _ref10, otherMetas, isLatestRemoteExistOnAllAccounts, _calendar, _calendarId2, _extractTitleAndSumma, title, summary, _ref11, reply, _status, _calendarId3, _remoteEventId, _extractTitleAndSumma2, _title, _summary, _ref12, _reply, _status2;

              return _regenerator.default.wrap(function _loop$(_context13) {
                while (1) {
                  switch (_context13.prev = _context13.next) {
                    case 0:
                      console.log('at top of while-loop for saga for event id:', id);
                      console.log('got message in chan, message:', message, 'will check newerMessages (which are newer then this current message) to see if this newer should cancel & ovveride this message');
                      console.log('will delay 5s to allow user to batch actions - for instance undo is allowed for 4sec, so that would cancel the create');
                      _context13.next = 5;
                      return (0, _effects.call)(_reduxSaga.delay, 5000);

                    case 5:
                      console.log('done delay');
                      _context13.next = 8;
                      return (0, _effects.flush)(chan);

                    case 8:
                      newerMessages = _context13.sent;
                      console.log('newerMessages in chan:', newerMessages, 'recall that current message is:', message);
                      message = newerMessages.last || message;
                      console.log('checked newerMessages, and decided message to act on is:', message);
                      _message3 = message, kind = _message3.kind;
                      _context13.next = 15;
                      return (0, _effects.select)(_selectors.selectEvent, id);

                    case 15:
                      event = _context13.sent;

                      if (event) {
                        _context13.next = 20;
                        break;
                      }

                      console.warn('EVENT NO LONGER EXISTS, so disccarding, and skipping switch block and skip to kill the channel this SHOULD NEVER HAPPEN');
                      _context13.next = 94;
                      break;

                    case 20:
                      meta = (0, _utils2.getPushMeta)(event, accountId, calendarId);
                      isRemoteExisting = meta.sid !== undefined;

                      if (kind === PK.create && isRemoteExisting) {
                        console.log('kind was create, but isRemoteExisting, so change this to update!');
                        kind = PK.update;
                      } else if (kind === PK.update && !isRemoteExisting) {
                        console.log('kind was update, but isRemoteExisting is false!!, so change this to create!');
                        kind = PK.create;
                      }

                      _context13.t0 = kind;
                      _context13.next = _context13.t0 === PK.delete ? 26 : _context13.t0 === PK.create ? 54 : _context13.t0 === PK.update ? 74 : 94;
                      break;

                    case 26:
                      _context13.next = 28;
                      return (0, _effects.select)(_selectors2.selectActiveCalendar);

                    case 28:
                      _context13.t1 = _context13.sent;

                      if (_context13.t1) {
                        _context13.next = 31;
                        break;
                      }

                      _context13.t1 = {
                        id: 'primary'
                      };

                    case 31:
                      calendar = _context13.t1;
                      _calendarId = calendar.id;
                      remoteEventId = meta.sid;

                      if (!isRemoteExisting) {
                        _context13.next = 39;
                        break;
                      }

                      _context13.next = 37;
                      return (0, _effects.call)(_fetch.default, "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/" + _calendarId + "/events/" + remoteEventId, {
                        method: 'delete'
                      });

                    case 37:
                      _ref10 = _context13.sent;
                      status = _ref10.status;

                    case 39:
                      if (!(!isRemoteExisting || status === 204 || status === 410)) {
                        _context13.next = 52;
                        break;
                      }

                      _context13.next = 42;
                      return (0, _effects.put)(patchEvent(id, {
                        pushMetaByAccCalId: (0, _defineProperty2.default)({}, accCalId, {
                          accCalId: accCalId,
                          accountId: accountId,
                          calendarId: _calendarId,
                          sid: undefined,
                          version: event.version
                        })
                      }));

                    case 42:
                      otherMetas = Object.values(event.pushMetaByAccCalId || {}).filter(function (meta) {
                        return meta.accCalId !== accCalId;
                      });
                      isLatestRemoteExistOnAllAccounts = otherMetas.every(function (otherMeta) {
                        return [undefined, event.version].includes(otherMeta.version);
                      });
                      _context13.next = 46;
                      return (0, _effects.select)(_selectors.selectEvent, id);

                    case 46:
                      event = _context13.sent;

                      if (!(isLatestRemoteExistOnAllAccounts && !(0, _utils2.testIfRecording)(event))) {
                        _context13.next = 50;
                        break;
                      }

                      _context13.next = 50;
                      return (0, _effects.put)(_deleteEvent(id));

                    case 50:
                      _context13.next = 53;
                      break;

                    case 52:
                      console.warn('failed to delete, i should keep retrying this, until another message comes in to chan canceling this one?');

                    case 53:
                      return _context13.abrupt("return", "break");

                    case 54:
                      _context13.next = 56;
                      return (0, _effects.select)(_selectors2.selectActiveCalendar);

                    case 56:
                      _context13.t2 = _context13.sent;

                      if (_context13.t2) {
                        _context13.next = 59;
                        break;
                      }

                      _context13.t2 = {
                        id: 'primary'
                      };

                    case 59:
                      _calendar = _context13.t2;
                      _calendarId2 = _calendar.id;
                      _extractTitleAndSumma = (0, _utils2.extractTitleAndSummary)(event.memo), title = _extractTitleAndSumma.title, summary = _extractTitleAndSumma.summary;
                      _context13.next = 64;
                      return (0, _effects.call)(_fetch.default, "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/" + _calendarId2 + "/events", {
                        method: 'post',
                        body: {
                          summary: title,
                          description: summary,
                          start: {
                            dateTime: (0, _moment.default)(event.start).toISOString()
                          },
                          end: {
                            dateTime: (0, _moment.default)(event.end).toISOString()
                          },
                          location: event.location
                        }
                      });

                    case 64:
                      _ref11 = _context13.sent;
                      reply = _ref11.reply;
                      _status = _ref11.status;

                      if (!(_status === 200)) {
                        _context13.next = 72;
                        break;
                      }

                      _context13.next = 70;
                      return (0, _effects.put)(patchEvent(id, {
                        pushMetaByAccCalId: (0, _defineProperty2.default)({}, accCalId, {
                          accCalId: accCalId,
                          accountId: accountId,
                          calendarId: _calendarId2,
                          sid: reply.id,
                          version: event.version
                        })
                      }));

                    case 70:
                      _context13.next = 73;
                      break;

                    case 72:
                      console.warn('failed to insert event, i should keep retrying this, until another message comes in to chan canceling this one?');

                    case 73:
                      return _context13.abrupt("return", "break");

                    case 74:
                      _context13.t3 = _lodash.get;
                      _context13.next = 77;
                      return (0, _effects.select)();

                    case 77:
                      _context13.t4 = _context13.sent;
                      _context13.t5 = ['prefs', 'calendar', 'id'];
                      _calendarId3 = (0, _context13.t3)(_context13.t4, _context13.t5, 'primary');
                      _remoteEventId = meta.sid;
                      _extractTitleAndSumma2 = (0, _utils2.extractTitleAndSummary)(event.memo), _title = _extractTitleAndSumma2.title, _summary = _extractTitleAndSumma2.summary;
                      _context13.next = 84;
                      return (0, _effects.call)(_fetch.default, "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/" + _calendarId3 + "/events/" + _remoteEventId, {
                        method: 'put',
                        body: {
                          summary: _title,
                          description: _summary,
                          start: {
                            dateTime: (0, _moment.default)(event.start).toISOString()
                          },
                          end: {
                            dateTime: (0, _moment.default)(event.end).toISOString()
                          },
                          location: event.location
                        }
                      });

                    case 84:
                      _ref12 = _context13.sent;
                      _reply = _ref12.reply;
                      _status2 = _ref12.status;

                      if (!(_status2 === 200)) {
                        _context13.next = 92;
                        break;
                      }

                      _context13.next = 90;
                      return (0, _effects.put)(patchEvent(id, {
                        pushMetaByAccCalId: (0, _defineProperty2.default)({}, accCalId, {
                          accCalId: accCalId,
                          accountId: accountId,
                          calendarId: _calendarId3,
                          sid: _reply.id,
                          version: event.version
                        })
                      }));

                    case 90:
                      _context13.next = 93;
                      break;

                    case 92:
                      console.warn('failed to update event, i should keep retrying this, until another message comes in to chan canceling this one?');

                    case 93:
                      return _context13.abrupt("return", "break");

                    case 94:
                      if (!buf.isEmpty()) {
                        _context13.next = 103;
                        break;
                      }

                      console.log('buf is empty for event id:', id, 'so destroying channel and quiting pushSaga for it');
                      chan.close();
                      delete pushChanById[id];
                      _context13.next = 100;
                      return (0, _effects.put)(patchEvent(id, {
                        status: undefined
                      }));

                    case 100:
                      return _context13.abrupt("return", "break|PUSH_MESSAGE_LOOP");

                    case 103:
                      console.log('at bottom of while-loop, and there are more messages so immediately take next message, for saga for event id:', id);
                      _context13.next = 106;
                      return (0, _effects.take)(chan);

                    case 106:
                      message = _context13.sent;
                      console.log('got another message from chan while at bottom, message:', message);

                    case 108:
                    case "end":
                      return _context13.stop();
                  }
                }
              }, _loop, this);
            });

          case 16:
            if (!true) {
              _context14.next = 26;
              break;
            }

            return _context14.delegateYield(_loop(), "t0", 18);

          case 18:
            _ret = _context14.t0;
            _context14.t1 = _ret;
            _context14.next = _context14.t1 === "break" ? 22 : _context14.t1 === "break|PUSH_MESSAGE_LOOP" ? 23 : 24;
            break;

          case 22:
            return _context14.abrupt("break", 26);

          case 23:
            return _context14.abrupt("break", 26);

          case 24:
            _context14.next = 16;
            break;

          case 26:
          case "end":
            return _context14.stop();
        }
      }
    }, _marked13, this);
  }
```

Comment: Yes, it's a bug: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8709

Comment: Try your cases without curly braces. Like this case A: , not case A: {

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much @Bergi!!!!! I was racking my brains non-stop for this!!!!! I have to work on learning how to search github better. Thank you so much for saving me from more headache!!! I have voted to close the topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a reported bug on Github thanks to @Bergi comment - https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8709

Comment: Your react issue was auto-closed. You need to stick to the issue template.